# How to draw a combo graph in Google Chart vertically with dual axes at top and bottom?

Tags: google-visualization

I've got a Google Chart ComboGraph in vertical orientation and I'd like to display the dependent axis (horizontal one in this configuration) both at the bottom and at the top of the graph.

For horizontal orientation, a hack I can use to achieve this is to create a dummy second axis - then the two axes display on left and right of the graph. But this doesn't translate to top and bottom for a vertical orientation.

I don't mind using some JS fiddling to achieve the result but it's not clear to me if this is possible - any ideas?

Here's an example graph - there's also the issue that the viewWindow doesn't seem to be respected for either axis, as can be seen by looking at the 'horizontal' view (the 'tracking' and 'candle' should fit together):

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawVisualization);

    function drawVisualization() {
        // Some raw data (not necessarily accurate)
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
             ['Value', 'Candle', '', '', '', 'Points', 'Tracking'],
             ['1',  165,      938,         938,              998,          450,      938],
             ['2', -150,      599,         599,             1268,          288,      599],
             ['3',  157,      587,         587,              807,          397,      587],
             ['4',  139,      615,         615,              968,          215,      615],
             ['5',  136,      629,         629,             1026,         1200,      629]
        ]);

        var options = {
            orientation:'vertical',
            title : '',
            vAxis: {title: ''},
            hAxis: {
                0: {
                    title: '0',
                    viewWindow: { min: -200, max: 1200 },
                    minorGridlines: { count: 4, color:'#E9E9E9' }
                },
                1: {
                    title: '1',
                    viewWindow: { min: -200, max: 1200 }
                }
            },
            seriesType: 'candlesticks',
            series: {
                1: {type: 'line', pointsVisible:true,lineWidth:0,color:'#FF9955'},
                2: {type:'bars',color:'#AAAAFF'},
                0: {color: 'blue', targetAxisIndex: 1}
        }
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart_div" style="width: 900px; height: 500px;"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Top-X Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#top-x-charts) are only available via standard config options on a *Material* chart
However, *Material* charts do not support "combo" charts...

But if all you want are the same axis labels displayed at the top,
you can clone them and change the `'y'` attribute manually,
when the `'ready'` event fires

see following working snippet,
use chart method --> `getChartLayoutInterface().getBoundingBox('chartarea')`
to find the top coordinate of the chart area...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['corechart']
}).then(function () {
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
         ['Value', 'Candle', '', '', '', 'Points', 'Tracking'],
         ['1',  165,      938,         938,              998,          450,      938],
         ['2', -150,      599,         599,             1268,          288,      599],
         ['3',  157,      587,         587,              807,          397,      587],
         ['4',  139,      615,         615,              968,          215,      615],
         ['5',  136,      629,         629,             1026,         1200,      629]
    ]);

    var options = {
        orientation:'vertical',
        title : '',
        vAxis: {title: ''},
        hAxis: {
            0: {
                title: '0',
                viewWindow: { min: -200, max: 1200 },
                minorGridlines: { count: 4, color:'#E9E9E9' }
            },
            1: {
                title: '1',
                viewWindow: { min: -200, max: 1200 }
            }
        },
        seriesType: 'candlesticks',
        series: {
            1: {type: 'line', pointsVisible:true,lineWidth:0,color:'#FF9955'},
            2: {type:'bars',color:'#AAAAFF'},
            0: {color: 'blue', targetAxisIndex: 1}
        }
    };

    var container = document.getElementById('chart_div');
    var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(container);

    google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
      var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
      var svg = container.getElementsByTagName('svg')[0];
      var axisLabels = svg.getElementsByTagName('text');
      var coords = chartLayout.getBoundingBox('chartarea');

      Array.prototype.forEach.call(axisLabels, function(label) {
        if (label.getAttribute('text-anchor') === 'middle') {
          var topAxisLabel = label.cloneNode(true);
          var yCoord = coords.top - parseInt(topAxisLabel.getAttribute('font-size'));
          topAxisLabel.setAttribute('y', yCoord);
          svg.appendChild(topAxisLabel);
        }
      });
    });

    chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

note: changes made manually in this way will not show when using chart method --> `getImageURI()`
if you need to get an image, you can use [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/) instead...

Comment: Yes, that does exactly what I wanted - thanks! Just a quick note though, if we need IE compatibility we can't use Promises.